# SM_USER for every requests from SIteminder (Static requests as well)

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, siteminder

Siteminder sending SM_USER (userId) back to application for all requests including static resource requests. we dont need userId in every request header except for specified Url.
Can anyone help how can avoid this in Spring boot+Siteminder configuration?

below using Siteminder filter,

@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(siteminderFilter(), RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter.class)
        ......
        ......
    }

@Bean
    public RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter siteminderFilter() throws Exception {
        RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter filter = new RequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter();
        filter.setPrincipalRequestHeader(smEmpID);
        filter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManagerBean());
        filter.setCheckForPrincipalChanges(true);
        filter.setExceptionIfHeaderMissing(false);
        return filter;

Thanks.

Comment: i need to avoid reading userId from all static request header.

Comment: you can ignore patterns for static resources something like: `@Override public void configure(WebSecurity web){web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/static-files/**");}`

Comment: still we see same issue, thanks

Comment: What problem is it causing and how are you detecting it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set DisableUserNameVars=No in your ACO and it will stop sending SM_USER

For the urls you need userid you can setup custom header with userid like HTTP_SM_USER.

Please note, as per documentation, using SM_USER inside the application is not advisable.

For few other applications (like integrating with SAP or other apps) you must have SM_USER, so there you have no escape.